# Efficient Leveling System

Tags: php

I'm making a leveling system based on experience you have on the site. I already have all the experience stuff figured out, and how I want to do the leveling, but I need a more efficient way to do it. I know this would probably would be achieved using an array, but I don't really know how to go about doing that. Enough blabbering, though, this is what I'm trying to do...

Level 1 will be anything under 150 experience
Then I'm going to multiply that by 1.5, so
Level 2 will be anything under 225
Level 3 will be anything under 337.5 and so on. This is the inefficient way that I was going to do.

```
if($xp < 150){
$level = "1";
}elseif($xp < 225){
$level = "2";
}elseif($xp < 337.5){
$level = "3";
}
```

I could use a variable for the number and multiple by 1.5 (`$number*1.5`), but like I said before I don't really know how that'd work.

*Some more info.. 
I have a session file included on every page and I have queries that would check every time there is new experience earned and this code would be used to update the level on the database automatically.

Comment: You don't need to put the variable in quotes. `if( $xp < 150 )` would work. Prevents PHP from having to do a couple types of type cohersion...

Comment: I don't know why I did that haha, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$level = min(max((int)(log($xp / 100, 1.5) + 1), 1), $maxLevel);
```

That takes the *logarithm base 1.5* of xp/100 (i.e. the number of times you'd have to multiply 100 by to get $xp), then adds one (since log($x, 1.5) is less than one if $x is less than 1.5). The `min(max(..., minLevel), maxLevel)` construct lets you clamp the level to lie between 1 and `$maxLevel`, also avoiding any issues with negative levels (if `$xp` is sufficiently less than 150).

Comment: +1 for mathematical, infinitely scaleable method. Would suggest mentioning `min()` to cap the level if desired.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The only thing I noticed with this is that if someone is under 150 experience their level is in the negatives. I could just do `if($level < 0){ $level = "1"}` and that fixed it. Also, just in case anyone else uses this I changed it to `$level = round(log($xp / 100, 1.5)) + 1;` just so it would be a nicer number to store. That shouldn't negatively affect it, right? But thanks again!

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to avoid negative values and provide a level cap. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I'm still in high school, so the next time someone in my math class says you never use logarithms outside of school I'll have to show this to them! Haha, but it works like a charm. Wonderful explanation too, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did my level system. It's a little more advanced featuring skill points..

```
    <?php
    $level_up = ($level + 1);
if ($exp >= $max_exp)
    {
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET level=(level + 1) , max_exp=(exp * 1.05) , skill_points=(skill_points + 3) WHERE id='".$id."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
if ($exp >= $max_exp)
        echo '<div class="Leveled">' . 'You sucessfully leveled up to ' . $level_up . '!' . ' As a reward you were given 3 skill points!' . '</div>';
    }
    else
    {
    } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree. either objects or arrays would be best.

Something like:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'xp_required' => 150,
        'level' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'xp_required' => 225,
        'level' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'xp_required' => 337.5,
        'level' => 3
    )
);
$current_xp = 155;
foreach( $array as $reqs ){
    if( $current_xp > $reqs['xp_required'] ){
        $level = $reqs['level'];
    }
}
echo $level';
```

Comment: If numbers are the only things you're dealing with, I'd go with @nneonneo. This solution would work better if there are other things that need to be set. For instance, granting a user powers at certain levels. Where each level needs modular control.

Comment: You could also just do those tests later as special cases, e.g. `if($level > 5) grantSuperPowers();`

Comment: The only problem I had with doing it this way is I didn't want to have to do that for 50+ levels. Thanks for the reply, though!

Answer (score 0):

well at the moment once you grab the users exp you can have that code block as a function to constantly check for variations in exp levels, but use a ranged statement

```
 if($xp < 150){
     $level = "1";
  }elseif($xp > 150 && $xp < 225 ){
    $level = "2";
  }elseif($xp > 225 && $xp < 337.5){
    $level = "3";
  }
```